How to smooth between colored faces
To start with, I have vertex color and color the faces between them based on vertex color.
But as you can see in the images clearly that triangles are obvious. I want to find a way to smooth the color between faces so that the whole loop face can look nice. I think we can operate on

vertex color data (average them or something else)
shading nodes
...

By the way, smooth shading doesnt work

The easiest way is to add more geometry, eg. Subdivide simple.

Or use an Image Texture, depending on what your final goal is

can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

You will need more geometry - more vertexes. Each vertex can have a dot of paint around it in vertex paint mode so if you only have couple vertexes you can only do couple dots of paint. For better smoothing and more painting freedom just add more vertexes.
